# Rails: Filter nested attribute in scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

My models have the following relation:

`Building` has many `Room`s that have many `Bed`s that have many `Accommodation`s,

and I want to render all `Building`s but with `Accommodation`s created in a date range. From other answers I understood that I need to create scope for `Building` model, but I could not understand how to filter such nested attributes inside this scope.

EDIT:

Lets say I have `Building` 1, 2 and 3. Each `Building` has it's own `Room`s which have `Bed`s which have `Accommodation`s. Lets say only `Building` 1 has one `Accommodation` that is in range. So the returned data must be:

```
Building 1
    ...
    Room n
      ...
        Bed n
         Accommodation that is in range
        Bed n+1
      ...
    ...
Building 2 (accommodation arrays in beds are empty since there are no accommodations that are in range)
    ...
Building 3 (accommodation arrays is beds are empty since there are no accommodations that are in range)
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

To avoid having to write excessively nested join queries [setup indirect relations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) in your model:

```
class Building
  has_many :rooms
  has_many :beds, though: :rooms
  has_many :accommodations, through: :beds
end

class Room
  belongs_to :building
  has_many :beds
  has_many :accommodations, through: :beds
end

class Bed
  belongs_to :room
  has_many :accommodations
  has_one :building, through: :room
end

class Accommodation
  belongs_to :bed
  has_one :room, through: :bed
  has_one :building, through: :room
end
```

This will let you query `building.accommodations` directly and ActiveRecord will join the intermediate tables for you.

Then just use a [Range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html) when querying:

```
Building.includes(:accommodations)
        .where(accommodations: { created_at: start_time..end_time })
```

This will construct a `WHERE 'accommodations.created_at' BETWEEN ...` with most database drivers.

Another key piece to the puzzle is that you are not filtering nested attributes. Rather what is happening above is that you are using a [join and setting conditions on the joined table](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables).

Comment: this only includes buildings where accommodation creation date is in range, but i only want to filter accommodations and return all buildings

Comment: Then use a left outer join instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Building
  scope :accomodations_for_dates, lambda { |start_date, end_date|
    joins(rooms: [beds: :accomodations]).where("accomodations.created_at >= #{start_date} AND accomodations.end_date <= #{end_date}")
  }
end
```

With PostgreSQL and MySQL databases you can use `BETWEEN`:

```
"accomodations.created_at BETWEEN #{start_date} AND #{end_date}"
```

To return all building but with filtered accommodations you'd want to use includes:

```
includes(rooms: [beds: :accomodations]).where(accomodations: { created_at: start_date..end_date })
```

Comment: this only includes buildings where accommodation creation date is in range, but i only want to filter accommodations and return all buildings

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev your comment makes no sense to me, unfortunately. Could you rephrase it?

Comment: lets say i have buildings 1, 2, 3 and building 1 has 1 accommodation that is in range and 1 that is not, other buildings don't have at all. your solution will return building 1 with all accommodations, while i need to return building 1 with accommodation in range and other buildings

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev So what will be the result? The building with matching accommodations?

Comment: what i meant is that i need accommodations filtered inside buildings, not only buildings with accommodations satisfying condition

Comment: yeap, pretty much it

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev The query I composed will return only buildings which have accommodations created within given range of dates.

Comment: yeah, sorry if my question was not properly explained, that's not the query i need

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev you do realize, that neither me nor [at]max (who has give another answer) understood your question, then? I am afraid you do not really understand it either, because I don't see what you mean by neither of your comments... Try to rephrase the initial question in a way everyone will understand it.

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev Ok, I think you could change the `joins` to `includes` in my query. Check it

Comment: still returns only one building and no others